# A mathematical area capable of describing nonstationary game-like problem

Tags: mathematical-modeling, machine-learning

Here is my definition of the problem that I am trying to model:
Let's have two agents and an environment. Each agent can do two types of actions. They are either supporting the environment or don't. The environment has a variable (denoted by *s*) of quantitive nature, let us assume it can take values from 0 to 1. If the agents decide to support the environment the *s*' value increases in next moment *t*. If they both decide to support the environment the outcome will be exactly the same as if only was willing to do that. Moreover, each agent has limited number of "supportions".

The goal is to maximize the function:
$ F=\sum_{t \in T} s_t  $
where $ s_t $ is value of the variable at time (round/turn) *t*

An example:

Legend

A1 -> AS - the agent 1 decides to support the environment

A2 -> NS - the agent 2 decides to not support the environment

s = 0.7 - value of the variable s is equal to 0.7

A1.NuSu = 3 - number of supportions available to agent 1 is equal to 3

I assume that supporting the environment increases value of s by 0.1 in next "turn". If no agent decided to support env. then in *t+2* *s*' value will decrease by 0.1. Environment var. value stats with 0 and cannot decrease further, it also cannot exceed 1. Each agent has two supportions avaiable at the begining of the game. Game will last for 10 rounds.

Turn 1

A1.NuSu = 3, A2.NuSu = 3, s = 0

A1 -> NS

A2 -> AS

Turn 2

A1.NuSu = 3, A2.NuSu = 2, s = 0.1

A1 -> NS

A2 -> AS

Turn 3

A1.NuSu = 3, A2.NuSu = 1, s = 0.2

A1 -> NS

A2 -> NS

Turn 4

A1.NuSu = 3, A2.NuSu = 1, s = 0.2

A1 -> NS

A2 -> AS

Turn 4

A1.NuSu = 3, A2.NuSu = 0, s = 0.3

A1 -> NS

A2 -> NS

Turn 5

A1.NuSu = 3, A2.NuSu = 0, s = 0.3

A1 -> AS

A2 -> NS

Turn 6

A1.NuSu = 2, A2.NuSu = 0, s = 0.4

A1 -> NS

A2 -> NS

Turn 7

A1.NuSu = 3, A2.NuSu = 0, s = 0.4

A1 -> AS

A2 -> NS

Turn 8

A1.NuSu = 1, A2.NuSu = 0, s = 0.5

A1 -> NS

A2 -> NS

Turn 9

A1.NuSu = 1, A2.NuSu = 0, s = 0.5

A1 -> AS

A2 -> NS

Turn 10

A1.NuSu = 0, A2.NuSu = 0, s = 0.6

A1 -> NS

A2 -> NS

I guess this does not apply in typical ML because of non-stationarity (example does not show this but environment can decrase its "value" so it does matter when AND how agents are acting).

And finally my question : is there any theory how to deal with such problems in general?

Comment: I guess it can be described by Game Theory.

Comment: Is the use of the abbreviation NS for both "not supporting" and "number of supportions" intended to confuse people?

Comment: @AndreasBlass edited, thx for pointing that out